# MongoDB extract all elements from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to extract all elements from an array in aggregation pipeline?

For example, I want to get all parents' categories. I have created a collection `category` where I have key `parents`. `parents` is an array with ObjectId's as a reference to the parent category.

So, with `$graphlookup` I can find all parents categories, but their categories are returned only as a key of the array. So I need to extract all elements from property parents and insert in one level with children categories.

Here is the example of what I have now and what I want. https://repl.it/@KostyaZgara/mongo

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator.

Comment: It seems a simple javascript logic can help you achieve the transformation you want, may I ask why you want it to be part of the pipeline?

Comment: Can you post an example of the documents in your collection, and your current `aggregate` pipeline operation?